# Which data source for WPF application?

Tags: sql-server, wpf, security, desktop-application

I have to implement a very simple WPF application to register medical visits. 
At each visit the doctor (user) will fill static fields with the patient status and save that.
I was thinking to use SQL Server express to save the patients personal data (Name, address, prescriptions). However since the requirements are very easy (no need to execute reports or heavy data manipulation) mainly based on SELECT/INSERT operation, maybe there would be a better way to store data?

The goal is to let the application and the data source run on an USB stick, therefore security should also be provided in order to avoid being able to access the database in case the USB pen would be lost or stolen. Also because of this requirement I was pointing to SQL express.
Can anyone suggest a better approach or confirm the use of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your requirements are simple and small, I would suggest a NoSQL solution.  Check out [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/home) as it is .NET based and very popular.

Going with NoSQL saves you from the complexity and size of SQL, but it also gives you more features -- and saves your from having to implement it yourself -- than if you rolled your own file based storage mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for an embedded database

[Good ebmedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639846/what-is-a-good-embedded-database-to-use-with-c)

With embedded you don't need  a separate install of the database.

As for security.
I don't see how Express would have more security than an embedded.
If the USB pen is lost then they are gong to be able to hack the data on it.
You could encrypt with a long key.
Your best security is don't lose the USB.

The problem you have with a key is that if it is short enough for a human to enter then it can be hacked by brute force. If you put a long key on a CD so it is hard to crack then you are stuck with don't lose the CD.  If you look at HIPPA if you are an open network then you have to use an encryption key of a certain length.  But that is not data going over a network (I assume).

Is the device you are putting USB into trusted? If not game over.

Comment: +1 Blam for the suggestion. Yes, do not lose the USB would be the best, but it might always happen. I will leave the answer open for another day in case any other wants to add a new one. Thanks!